# Pointing domain and subdomain to the same firebase app

Tags: firebase, cname, firebase-hosting, a-records

Custom domain is currently setup with A record pointing to the IP of the firebase AND wildcard CNAME record pointing to the same app.

**dig +short mydomain.com**

```
151.101.65.75
151.101.1.75
```

**dig +short abc.mydomain.com**

```
myapp.firebaseapp.com.
app-cert.firebaseapp.com.
151.101.65.75
151.101.1.75
```

The problem is that "abc.mydomain.com" is redirecting to "mydomain.com" with a 301 response.

Is the problem in how the domain is setup or on the firebase end?

EDIT reply from the firebase support is:

"Unfortunately, since you've already connected your domain mydomain.com your firebase app, all redirects will go through that URL. and not to your firebase app.
"

This reply is so confusing and makes no sense IMO.

Comment: Are you trying to have `mydomain.com` and `abc.mydomain.com` point to different web sites/projects?

Comment: @frank No, both URLs should point to the same project.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 2020-03-30

For several years now it's actually been entirely possible to have a subdomain pointing to a different Firebase Hosting site than the apex domain. This answer has been out of date. Happy Hosting!

<del>Firebase Hosting presently only allows one canonical domain for your project -- if you specified `mydomain.com` and then point `abc.mydomain.com` to Firebase Hosting, it will redirect, as you saw.</del>

<del>We're considering some improvements in this area for the future, but at present all non-canonical domains will redirect.</del>

Comment: Thanks for the reply @michael. So this is a firebase issue/limitation not an misconfigured domain on my side?

Comment: There is a similar discussion of this topic here. fyi. http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/151v5cgnv9/firebase-two-separate-apps-one-on-main-domain-one-on-subdomain

Comment: Is still a valid answer? or have has Firebase changed its ways?

Comment: Updated -- totally possible now!